# how to remove authentication from an MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning MVC from the internet, using Visual Studio 2013.

After finishing my project and deploying it to a host via "publish", it worked perfectly (locally too).

Though now, the app throws an authentication form on login (after publishing). locally it doesn't do that. I want to remove authintication totally, since the site (with all its pages) is open.

I'm sorry for the dull question, but I searched and cannot find a clue about my problem precisely, probably due to utter ignorance in that side of the framework..please help.

I tried to manually trace things, I have an "startup.cs" which contains :

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

        }
    }
```

This directs me to the file "Startup.Auth" which automatically has :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
            // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
...
```

When trying to remove the function call in Startup.cs , the project immediately throws a very basic login menu.

Then, In my project's settings, I kept both "windows authentication" and "anonymous authentication" DISABLED. Kept the function call in "Startup.cs" too.

But in that scenario it throws "this page has a redirect loop"..

Please help me, I'm very confused about this : I want to totally remove authentication.

Comment: Removing the ConfigureAuth(app) should remove the authentication checks.  What does "throws a very basic login menu" mean?  If you're using the starter app and you do disable authentication I'd expect the app to behave a little weird.  The starter app is very simple and most of it is just login/user management. Take that away and it's just a home page.  So you can't just remove authentication and expect everything else to work as normal when 'everything else' is mainly stuff about or reliant on authentication.

Comment: A login form shows up form prompting username & password ; just like in triggering a protected FTP on a site.

Comment: But can you navigate elsewhere on the site? Is the login form just the default home page anyway?

Comment: @jamesGaunt no, I totally can't. The login form is not the default ; the site is built, has many controllers & views too. Yet is should make the user land at "home/index" which has no login forms of any kind.

Comment: @JamesGaunt Thank you so much, you provided me with the solution !. I completely deleted both "Startup.cs" and "Startup.Auth", republished, though the site says : "- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.",,,,," I went back and removed all Owin references, then deleted the whole project from server, replaced it with the new version, then edited my server's default pages to make it only one page (i.e the global.asax file of my project) then it worked perfectly. The owin security caused most of the trouble. Thank you so much for telling me it's okay to delete that !

Answer (score 4):

You should just [enable anonymous authentication in IIS settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244(v=ws.10).aspx) for your website.

Additionally, if you are using AuthorizeAttribute, you can mark your controllers/actions which should be accessed anonymously with AllowAnonymousAttribute. Anonymous authentication still should be enabled in IIS.
If you are using AuthorizeAttribute and are not able to remove it or mark actions with AllowAnonymous, you should manually create some mock user identity. But this is a question for another discussion.

To avoid redirection to the login page, you should set authentication mode to "None" in your web.config

Comment: thank you, I marked all my controllers with the [AllowAnonymous] attribute too.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the following code in web.config

```
<modules>
   <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

Comment: this is really awersome!

Answer (score 2):

I  have commented/removed `ConfigureAuth(app)` in `Startup.cs` and added  `[AllowAnonymous]` to my Home controller. You can add this  to any controller you want to redirect to. If you want to redirect to different controller than `Home` please don't forgot to make changes in `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set None mode in your web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
```

eventually Web.Release.config

Comment: I added that to my web.config, along with :     <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" /> but no success..